# How does the Drive resource in EOS work? Can we store alot of text data and use it like a mysql database?

Tags: ram, database

Ram is expensive for storing user data. EOS has the drive resources for storing data. How much does it cost compared to ram? And is it intended to be used like a mysql database for storing user data? Example: Storing user profile information such as address, phone, email, and bio?

Answer (score 1):

There is no "Drive"-Ressource and no public blockchain is intended to store personal data like address, phone, email etc.